# Extracting friends' likes data of facebook

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, information-retrieval

I am making a tool that will predict the likes on a certain post using the data of friends likes using information retrieval and machine learning but for that I need the data.Can anyone help me with how to get the data of my friends likes.I just want to extract which friend has likes which post?

Comment: You can only get likes from people that have given your app user_likes permission

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It is easy. Just login into your website with certain permission like user_friends (for now you can try it in graph api explorer) and then you can find likes of any posts of your friends with this code:

```js
FB.api(
  '/me',
  'GET',
  {"fields":"id,name,friends{likes,name}"},
  function(response) {
      // Insert your code here
  }
);
```

For now, you can try the following query in graph api explorer and check if that is what you want:

```
me?fields=id,name,friends{likes,name}
```

Comment: this only works for friends who authorized your app with the user_likes permission.